# Gson model with a variable handel multiple data type values

Tags: android, web-services, gson

IN my app a webservice return address as string and another webservice return address as a object. SO is this possible to have two variable one as string and second one as object. so model will assign value according to webservice response data type.

Below is code -

```
public class UserInfoModel implements java.io.Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = -3815624976763029102L;
     private String user_name;    
     private String address;

     public String getUserName() {
        return user_name;
     }

     public void setUserName(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
     }

     public String getAddress() {
        return user_name;
     }

     public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
     }
}
```

is this possible to have another variable in my model with same name address, which will be a class like AddressModel.

Please suggest any solution. TIA

Comment: It is not possible to have two variables with same name inside a single class. And `address as a object` — object of which type?

Comment: object as class type

Comment: It is a very bad practice to use same key for different types of objects. Your problem might be solved by designing your own `ConverterFactory`. But I am not sure how to make it. You should do some research on it.